# 'undeclared identifier' compiler error on TThread.Synchronize() method

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-6

**Compiler says undeclared identifier:**

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil, sync.Execute);
```

probably I'm using old version, so how to correct this error ?

maybe to overload it, can anybody help, I'm new to delphi and I want to install a delphi component on c++ builder. I need to fix above error, which i don't know how.

I'm using BCB6.
I'm trying to install Delphi Chromium Embedded on C++ Builder to use it in a old project

Comment: sorry, I'm using C++ Builder 6

Comment: The code you showed is Delphi code, not C++ code.  The C++ equivalent is `TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &sync->Execute);`, however that version of `Synchronize()` does not exist in BCB6.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I'm trying to install Delphi Chromium Embedded on C++ Builder to use it in a old project.

Comment: In [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18643146/33732) you said you had successfully used Chromium Embedded a "long time ago." Maybe you should try using the revision of that project that was current at the time you last used it instead of using the latest revision.

Comment: the problem is that my OS was reinstalled and i did installed again bcb6 and now i'm trying to install chromium

Comment: You don't use revision control?

Answer (score 4):

The code is written for a more modern version of BCB/Delphi. The Synchronize class method was added relatively recently (much more recently than BCB6) and your compiler error clearly indicates that your version is too old. The component you are trying to use does not support your compiler.

Possible solutions involve upgrading, or rewriting the code to match your version.

Comment: Quite recently? It's in D2007 (the oldest version I have here - I have D7 on another system I can check later).

Comment: @KenWhite In Delphi recent is all relative. Delphi 7 is old, and everything else is modern! :-)

Comment: @David Heffernan yeah I know that possible solution is to rewrite the code, but I'm not much experienced in delphi.  I'm trying to install Delphi Chromium Embedded on C++ Builder 6 to use it in a old project

Comment: In that case you must upgrade

Comment: I guess that's a good point. I wouldn't go back to Delphi 7 unless you paid me **a lot**. :-) (And +1, BTW.)